# including external library in Yii

Tags: php, class, namespaces, yii

How can I call these library functions from anywhere in my Yii app? I have a library:

```
#mylib.php

<?php
class MyLib {
    public function foo()
    {
        echo "hello!";
    }
}
```

and want to be able to call this function throughout my Yii app:

```
MyLib::foo();
```

I don't know where to place my library or how/where to import it. This is just an example of what I'm trying to do but I am trying to make a library that has multiple namespaces so I can access the library and have access to all the namespaces after importing it.

Comment: [Using 3rd party libraries in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several ways.

1. Register libraries' autoloader:

   ```
   // Enable Zend autoloader
   spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload')); // Disable Yii autoloader
   Yii::import('site.common.lib.*'); // Add Zend library to include_path
   Yii::import('site.common.lib.Zend.Loader.Autoloader', true); // Require Zend autoloader
   spl_autoload_register(array('Zend_Loader_Autoloader', 'autoload')); // Register Zend autoloader
   spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload')); // Register Yii autoloader
   ```
2. Add library to the import section in your config/main.php:

   ```
   return array(           
       // Autoloading
       'import' => array(
           'application.lib.*',
           'application.components.*',
           'site.common.extentions.YiiMongoDbSuite.*',
       ),
   );
   ```
3. Autoloading anywhere in your application:

   ```
   Yii::import('application.lib.*');
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Place your library in the vendors folder (under protected folder)
supposing (all your classes are in MyLib folder)
you do like this:

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.MyLib.*');
```

Comment: In addition to this, if you have a lot of files like this to include, just put them in '/protected/components' Yii will include all files in this directory.

Answer (score 2):

Explained right here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration

Answer (score 1):

I use Yii's own autoloader;

```
    //include auto loader class of vendor
    require dirname(__FILE__).'/mollie-api-php/src/Mollie/API/Autoloader.php';
    //Now register vendor autoloader class to Yii autoloader 
    Yii::registerAutoloader(array('Mollie_API_Autoloader','autoload'));
```